# Actualizar información dentro de un modal

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una página donde la información que se tiene dentro de un modal debe estar actualizando cada que la invoco con un botón. Dentro del modal genero un DataTable dinámica del cual a la función que invoco debe enviar un ID para que el DataTable se construya bajo ese valor. Dentro del HTML me traigo ese ID de la base de datos (el ID cambia con el click y lo actualiza en la BD) pero dicho valor como se carga en la página se actualiza cada que refresco en su totalidad. Estoy intentando actualizar la info de la página sin que se cierre el modal y que cada que la invoco con el botón actualice y pueda mostrarme correctamente el DataTable con el ID que necesito. Intente con una función en JavaScript que al dar click al botón me acutaliza pero lo hace para toda la página y no permite abrir el modal. Mi último intento es la función appendChild ():

HTML

```
<div id="adjEmisiones" class="modal" data-easein="flash" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AvanzaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="">Adjuntar Archivos para: <label id="txtAdjArchivo"></label></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="mdAdjArchivo">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container col-sm-12">
                        <form action="cargarArchivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <button class="form-control" type="submit" id="btnAdjuntar">Adjuntar Archivo</button>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="txtBox" name="idAdjArchivo" id="idAdjArchivo" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <?php 
                            $ID_EMISION = fnIDEMISIONARCHIVODJ($_SESSION['usuario']);
                            echo fnDTADJUNTOS($ID_EMISION);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="btnCerrarAdjA">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#dtEmisiones tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
        {
            var dtEmisiones = table.row(this).data();
            $("#idActEmision").val(dtEmisiones[0]); //ID EMISIÓN ACTUALIZAR
            $("#idEmision").val(dtEmisiones[0]); //ID EMISIÓN DESACTIVAR
            $("#idAdjArchivo").val(dtEmisiones[0]); // ID EMISIÓN CARGA FILE
            $("#txtNombreEmisionEdit").val(dtEmisiones[1]); //NOMBRE EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiSectorEdit").val(dtEmisiones[2]); //SECTOR EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiEmisorEdit").val(dtEmisiones[3]); //EMISOR EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiTipoEdit").val(dtEmisiones[4]); //TIPO EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiMontoEdit").val(dtEmisiones[5]); //MONTO EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiTasaEdit").val(dtEmisiones[6]); //TASA EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiFeeEdit").val(dtEmisiones[7]); //FEE EMISIÓN EDITAR
            $("#txtEmiPlazoEdit").val(dtEmisiones[8]); //PLAZO EMISIÓN EDITAR

            var Fecha = dtEmisiones[9];
            Fecha = convertDateFormat(Fecha);
            $("#EmiFechaEdit").val(Fecha); //FECHA EMISIÓN ACTUALIZAR

            var FechaLibro = dtEmisiones[10];
            FechaLibro = convertDateFormat(FechaLibro);
            $("#EmiFechaLibroEdit").val(FechaLibro); //FECHA LIBRO EMISIÓN ACTUALIZAR

            document.getElementById("txtNombreEmisionDesac").innerHTML=dtEmisiones[1]; //COMENTARIO DESACTIVAR
            document.getElementById("txtAdjArchivo").innerHTML=dtEmisiones[1]; //EMISIÓN ADJUNTAR ARCHIVO

            var IDEMISION = $("#idAdjArchivo").val();
            $.get("updateidadjarchivo.php",{IDEMISION: IDEMISION});

        });
```

Dentro de esta función en javascript mando a la BD el ID que necesito traer para que el llamado a PHP me construya el DataTable:

```
<div class="container col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <?php 
        $ID_EMISION = fnIDEMISIONARCHIVODJ($_SESSION['usuario']);
        echo fnDTADJUNTOS($ID_EMISION);
    ?>
</div>
```

Con este puente le indico que me traiga el ID que se almacena dentro de la tabla Usuarios y a traves de una función lo devuelve a $ID_EMISION y lo mande para construir la tabla fnDTADJUNTOS($ID_EMISION), pero no logro me actualice la info del modal:

```
function myFunction()
    {
      var node = document.createElement("mdAdjArchivo");
      var textnode = document.getElementById("idAdjArchivo");
      //var textnode = document.createTextNode("idAdjArchivo");
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      document.getElementById("dtAdjuntos").appendChild(node);
    }
```

El botón tiene la propiedad onclick='myFunction()', alguien tiene alguna sugerencia. Gracias

Comment: La mayoría de js es jQuery. Para actualizar cuando hagas click lo mejor será una llamada Ajax (con jQuery).

Comment: Gracias, si lo estoy revisando. Como adicional lo único que quiero actualizar es lo que esta en <?php ?> que esa función fnIDEMISIONARCHIVODJ actualice la solicitud a la BD para traer ese ID cada que se invoca al modal.